# How to write a function with an optional argument and variable length arguments?

Tags: php, function, variadic-functions, default-arguments

I want to implement a method inside a class like this:

```
class Query {
    public function orderBy($dir="asc", ...$fields){}
}
```

Where `$dir` is a default argument and `$field` is a variable-length argument using (`...`) token.

The problem is that variable-length argument must be declared at the end, and when I do this, the developer can’t skip the first argument to its default. How can I fix this?

Note that I don’t want to use `func_get_args()` because I want the developer to have some type hints.

Comment: Just use `...$fields`, and programmatically handle a default value for the first argument inside the method.  Then, author a good PHPDoc for the method that explains the method signature.

Comment: you could create a class "MethodArguments" that has those two parameters as properties, where the variable-length is passed in the constructer and the default has a setter function. But this all depends on how strict you wanna be/go.

Comment: @cale_b , …$fields is a separate argument, I want the developer to know which value should be assigned to which argument.

Comment: @cale_b let me update my example code so you can get the concept better

Comment: @cale_b I updated the example. $dir is ordering direction which can be "asc" or "desc", and $fields is the list of columns.

Comment: I get the concept.  But you're asking PHP to do something it won't do, so I get that you don't like it, but you've been given TWO workarounds....

Comment: @cale_b thanks for your help. So I think PHP should look back and make some changes :) because this is a condition that many developers may want to implement.

Comment: It's fairly standard in most languages (as far as I know) for optional arguments to NOT be allowed before required arguments.  If you think about it, it'd be pretty difficult to determine which argument goes where if you could put optional arguments before required arguments.  Using the variadic argument along with a "fixed" argument is what feels odd to me...

Answer (score 1):

This is simply not doable. PHP does not support this, and it doesn't make a lot of sense that it would. The only way this could work is by having named arguments, as in some other languages, making argument order irrelevant.

Furthermore, your requirment of using a variadic argument there is artificial, and not very useful. Just use an array and an optional order argument.

E.g.:

```
function orderBy(array $columns, string $order = 'asc') {
    // do your thing
}
```

Neater, simpler to understand to the method users, and complies with the language syntax.

If you want it to look "similar" to a variadic function, just call the method using a syntax like this:

```php
orderBy(["column1", "column5"]);

orderBy(["column2"], 'desc');
```

Comment: I know that I can use arrays instead of variable length arguments. But in that way, function call will be more complicated. By the way as you said and according to my own research I think there is no way to do that like my example. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but that’s not my answer. but it’s basically correct so I will vote it, but I don’t delete my question, maybe someday someone have another solution/answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to do was:

```
function tableHead($id=NULL, $class=NULL, ...$columnsHeads)
```

the "logical" function call when the first two arguments were not wanted to me was:

```
tableHead( , , "Dogs","Cars","Sausages");
```

Sadly PHP does not let you use a `,` as an empty default value. I get round this by sticking a `NULL, NULL,` as the first 2 arguments. Not ideal but will do for now!

(I am sure I have used empty `,` in some language 20 years ago to send an empty value - anyone know? - Or is it just wishful thinking?)

My *SOLUTION* (haha) is:

```
tableHead(NULL, NULL, "dogs","cars", "sausages");
```

Not ideal but it works. In normal usage the function will be called with `id` and `class` specified by variables. Personally I do not see anything unholy about combining variadic and optional arguments ... but you do have to be a bit careful!